# largest perimeter of a triangle with a non-zero area

Tags: algorithm

Given an integer array nums, return the largest perimeter of a triangle with a non-zero area formed from three of these lengths. If it is impossible to form any triangle of a non-zero area, return 0.

I can think about the brute force method, and another method is sorting the array given and iterating a loop backward and checking the condition for forming a triangle and returning the sum, is there any other method to solve this

Comment: Can't you just take the 3 largest numbers that can form a triangle (a+b < c, with a < b < c)? Is that what you mean by your other method with sorting? I'm pretty sure that's optimal.

Comment: Sorting and iterating the loop would have `O(nlogn)` complexity. Isn't that optimal enough for most use cases?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur After sorting, what do you do? How do you select the 3 values in a single iteration?

Comment: @Nelfeal Yes, but not trivial. How do you pick those 3 numbers? In general, testing any 3 numbers against each other is an *O(n^3)* problem.

Comment: @Berthur If the largest number doesn't fit with the two below, it won't fit with any other pair, so you can remove it from the list and repeat. That's a linear traversal of a sorted list.

Comment: @Nelfeal Then that is the key condition one needs to realize in order to solve this in sub-quadratic time :)

Comment: @Berthur It is my impression that this linear reverse traversal is exactly what OP means with his "other method" and that he is asking for yet another method.

Comment: @Nelfeal Fair enough. OP's comparison with brute force makes me wonder about that, but let's see if they got their answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best algorithm that I can think of is to put the numbers into a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), instead of sorting the array.  Usually it will be `O(n)` to make the heap and `O(1)` to find the triangle.  The worst case time is if no numbers satisfy the triangle condition, and therefore it would take `O(n log(n))` comparisons.  This worst case can only be hit if you allow big integers into the mix.  With 64-bit integers, say, the worst case is `O(n)`.

Given that you have to look at every element, you can't do better than `O(n)` average time.  And all of the tricks for fixed sized integers, like a radix sort, won't help much.

Even in the arbitrary integer situation, it is still very good.

Suppose that we had a comparison based algorithm with a worst case of `o(n log(n))`.  Then by tracking the comparisons made and applying Kahn's algorithm for a topological sort, you'd have a comparison based sort that is `o(n log(n))`, which is well-known to be impossible.

I'm having trouble finding a non-comparison based algorithm for integers of arbitrary size that might do better.

Comment: You can bin by bitlength for BigInts (assuming bitlength() is constant). Search the bins in pairs (bitlen L and L+1). Form a heap of their combined elements, proceed as before. If a triplet exists, it will be found within the first 5 elements. Else, early exit and move on to the next bin pair.